# Listfragment overlap

Tags: android

I want to create a list of music, but when I called the listfragment happens a overlap with previus layout

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2nS6.png)

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBTX8.png)

this is my code MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Fragment_list fl;
FragmentManager fm;
FragmentTransaction ft;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public void click(View v)
{
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setText("OK");
    fl=new Fragment_list();
    fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.replace(R.id.Contenedor,fl);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();

}
```

}

this is the listfragment code:

```
public class Fragment_list extends ListFragment {

MediaPlayer player;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceStatus)
{
    File scan= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
    File [] list=scan.listFiles();
    ArrayAdapter<File>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<File>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceStatus);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v,int position,long id)
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Posicion"+getListAdapter().getItem(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    player= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.parse(String.valueOf(getListAdapter().getItem(position))));
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();
}
```

}

I just want a Listfragment that can use addToBack, if I use FragmentTransition happens a overlap but addToBack works and if I use a xml fragment there is no overlap but I don't know how to use addToBack

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s only affect `Fragment`s and their `View`s. That `replace()` call isn't going to remove your `RelativeLayout`, or the `Button` inside it.

Comment: the what should I do, should change my relativelayout for a fragment?

Comment: That's an option. You'd have to transact that first `Fragment` dynamically, too, though, in `onCreate()`. Static `<fragment>`s defined in layouts can't be removed/replaced, so you'd end up with the same problem you have now, if you tried that.

Comment: it's works, using a fragment in another layout and using at setContentView but now I don't know how to use FragmentTransition.addToBackStack

Comment: What do you mean? You don't wanna back out from the first `Fragment`, do you?

Comment: No, sorry for my english, I mean that using setContentView I can't FragmentTransition in the same button because happens a crash, but using setContentView and press back the app come home of phone

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. If you want to [edit] your question with your current code, and point out the specific problems, maybe we can help further.

Comment: ok I will try..